# How to put command in terminal prompt without executing

Tags: function, input

I know you can simply put what you'd like to run:

```bsh
func()
{
    cd scripts
    ./excellent/script
}
```

but, what I'd like to do instead is have `./excellent/script` be put in
my commandline without being entered. This way when I run `func` it puts
what I need there and waits until I'm ready; think presentations:

```bsh
$ func
$ ./excellent/script
```

Comment: Only with xdotool or something similar

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391698/117549

Comment: also [How to fill terminal input line from file contents?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585390/how-to-fill-terminal-input-line-from-file-contents)

Comment: My current workaround is to use `xclip`: `echo "./excellent/script" | xclip`.

Answer (score 2):

This will basically accomplish it. What's really happening is that the command line prompt is just a fake one, but whatever you enter it executes right away, so it might as well be a real command prompt.

```
func() {
    cd scripts
    read -e -p '$ ' -i './excellent/script' command
    eval $command
}
```

If your prompt is more complicated than `$` , to make it look right, you might need to remove `-p '$ '` and add a line `echo -ne "[whatever] "` or similar before the `read` line.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using readline (say, with bash), you could tie a keystroke to a simple function that assigns the value of the text:

```bsh
bind -x '"\C-T": READLINE_LINE=./excellent/script'
```

This simply clobbers the current commandline (input) with the given text as soon as you hit <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>. The downside of this idea is running out of keyboard shortcuts if you have multiple examples you want to prepare.

Inspired by [mosvy's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308316/mosvy) [answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/578021/117549).